# Determine next map by mapsOrder array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have mapsOrder array and mapsData array of objects:

```
let mapsOrder = [1,2,1,3];
let mapData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    gates: [
      {
        toId: 2,
        coords: {
          x: 2,
          y: 42
        }
      },
      {
        toId: 3,
        coords: {
          x: 9,
          y: 4
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    gates: [
      {
        toId: 1,
        coords: {
          x: 6,
          y: 5
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    gates: [
      {
        toId: 1,
        coords: {
          x: 2,
          y: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I want to achieve is in loop basing on `mapsOrder` where `mapsOrder` array values are ids in `mapData`, designate gates to next map.

So we have loop that iterate 4 times and when:

- loop index is 1 current map is 1 next map is 2 and gates to next are `coords: { x: 2, y: 42 }`
- loop index is 2 current map is 2 next map is 1 and gates to next are `coords: { x: 6, y: 5 }`
- loop index is 3 current map is 1 next map is 3 and gates to next are `coords: { x: 9, y: 4 }`
- loop index is 4 current map is 3 next map is 1 and gates to next are `coords: { x: 2, y: 1 }`

last loop iteration see next map as first of `mapsOrder` array. I tried to do it myself by first determineting the id of next map like so:

```
for(let i = 0; i < mapsOrder.length; i++) {
  let nextMap;
  let currentMapId = mapData[mapsOrder[i] - 1].id;
  if(i === mapsOrder.length - 1) {
    nextMap = mapData[0].id   
  } else {
    nextMapId = mapData[mapsOrder[i]].id;    
  }

  console.log('Current map is: ', currentMapId, 'and the next map id is:', nextMapId)
  console.log('break-----')

}
```

but this console incorrect ids, [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvdYKm?editors=0010)

Comment: Can you alter the original array and its objects?

Comment: Yes I can do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about the original array then just use `shift` to get the next gate (`shift` will remove the gate from the array thus the next gate will be available when the object is encountered again). Use `find` to find the object from the array:

```
let result = mapsOrder.map(id =>
    mapData.find(o => o.id == id).gates.shift().coords
);
```

You may want to check if `find` actually finds something and the gates array contains something before using `shift`, here is a safer way:

```
let result = mapsOrder.map(id => {
    let obj = mapData.find(o => o.id == id);
    if(obj && obj.gates.length) {                  // if we found an object with the same id and that object still have gates
        return obj.gates.shift().coords;           // return the coords of the first gate and remove the gate from the array
    }                                              // otherwise, throw an error or something
});
```

**No altering:**

Instead of using `shift` from the previous example, we'll just use an object to track the gate index from the `gates` array:

```
let nextGateIndex = Object.create(null);                             // create a prototypeless object to track the next gate index for each object
let result = mapsOrder.map(id => {
    let obj = mapData.find(o => o.id == id);
    let index;
    if(nextGateIndex[id] == undefined) {
        index = 0;
    } else {
        index = nextGateIndex[id] + 1;
    }
    nextGateIndex[id] = index;
    if(obj && index < obj.gates.length) {
        return obj.gates[index].coords;
    }                                                                // throw error or something
});
```

Comment: That's gonna destroy gates in original array of objects right?

Comment: Yes. You said it's okay to alter the original array. If you don't want to alter it then just use an object to track the next gate index. I'll edit the answer

Comment: I don't care at the very moment I'm not certain sure if I will not need original array in the future code.

Comment: @BT101 Check out the no altering version. Tell me if you don't understand something. Good luck! :D

Answer (score 2):

If follow your description your loop should look like. Seems that you wand to use `id` and `toId` but using array indexes. It can be a good idea to replace arrays with objects.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/fyodor_e82/pen/axGbKB?editors=0012#0)

```
for(let i = 0; i < mapsOrder.length; i++) {
  let nextMap;
  let currentMapId = mapsOrder[i];
  if(i === mapsOrder.length - 1) {
    nextMapId = mapsOrder[0]   
  } else {
    nextMapId = mapsOrder[i + 1];    
  }
  let filteredMapData = mapData.filter(f => f.id == currentMapId);
  let filteredGates = filteredMapData.length > 0 ? filteredMapData[0].gates.filter(f => f.toId == nextMapId) : [];

  console.log('Current map is: ', currentMapId, 'and the next map id is:', nextMapId, 'gates:', filteredGates.length == 0 ? "no gates": filteredGates[0].coords)
  console.log('break----')

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function for javascript arrays as it is super quick.  This function will return an array filled with items from original matching some criteria (in this case, objects having the desired id).

```
for (let i = 0; i < mapsOrder.length; i++) {
    console.log(mapData.filter(mapDataItem => mapDataItem.id === mapsOrder[i]))
}
```

Comment: But I still don't know in first and third iteration if I should chose first or seond object from `gates` array.